# Node.js / JavaScript: get all parts of URL path hierarchy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm aware that you can get the query string of a URL like:

```
var url = require("url");

...

http.createServer((req,res) => console.log(url.parse(req.url).query))
```

But that's only if the variables are in a query-string format:

```
example.com/index.html?key=val&key2=val2
```

etc...

But what if I wanted to get the "variables" in the form of values if the url was in a format:

```
example.com/key/val/key2/val2
```

?

I could just split the array for `/`'s and then map it accordingly:

```
var pathParts = request.url.split("/").filter(x => x.length > 0).map(x => x.split("%20").join(" "));
```

but that would fail for a URL like this:

```
example.com/url/http://google.com
```

So how can I get each of the values separated by `/` as a unique array element, even if there are nested /'s ?

Comment: You should urlencode your strings anyway, that way it would be `example.com/url/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`

Comment: @MichałSadowski Oh cool, how do I do that? (and then decode?)

Comment: @MichałSadowski I realized about the encodeURIComponent and decodeUriComponent, but I realized it still doesn't help me: because I need to separate each value by one / at a time, how can I separate example.com/key/http: //yahoo.com/key2/http: //google.com (without the spaces)

Answer (score 1):

First, when you create a url you need to encode every part of it using `encodeURIComponent()`. This way you will get an url that is, for example: `example.com/url1/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com/url2/http%3A%2F%2Fbing.com`. Then reading it back is as simple as using:

```
let requestArray = request.url.split("/")
let requestDecodedArray = requestArray.map((el)=>decodeURIComponent(el))
```

Comment: When I run encodeURIComponent on a string like this question: (take out space after "https "):     encodeURIComponent("https ://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138803/node-js-javascript-get-all-parts-of-url-parth-hierchy/55139317#55139317") it encodes every "/" and doesn't differentiate between them at all, try it in the console

Comment: @bluejayke that's why you need to run it before composing the url, on every part of it, instead on it whole.

Comment: How should I do that, the user is the one who inputs the URL to their browser and I get it from request.url

Comment: Users generally don't input URL directly, but get it, for example, from links; otherwise you would never know what kind of input you will get. You need to solve it from UI perspective, but I bet it's gonna be done during link href composing.

Comment: I want to just use the URL as a variable